# How to bundle docker toolbox, dockerfile, docker-compose file inside an executable file?

Tags: docker, windows-installer, inno-setup, nsis, docker-toolbox

I want to create a windows executable file (.exe) which should install the docker toolbox (docker-machine,docker-compose,virtualbox) in windows.

I should also have to bundle the docker-compose and dockerfiles inside the .exe file. So that once the tool box is installed, it should call the docker-compose file and container should be started as i defined in the dockerfile.

I want to automate this process in a single click instead of allowing everyone to install all these components and start the containers manually.

Is it possible to accomplish this? i am trying to use NSIS or Inno setup.

Answer (score 3):

I think so.

If you bundle the docker toolbox installer inside your InnoSetup, you can call it using a "/silent" like parameter, then copy your docker-compose executable and create shortcuts which will call your docker-compose commands.

Don't include the docker file. Instead include the whole image using docker save and docker load. Or use docker-compose to download your image from a registry.

Regards

Comment: thanks for the suggestion. Can you please tel me why not to bundle the dockerfile ?

Comment: Because even in the case you distribute in the traditional way, you don't distribute the Dockerfile. The Dockerfile should be used as a reference or for extending. But for a packaged application it is not required for running containers only the image is required

Comment: I need to get some of the parameters for the container such as port, versions and few other things from the user while executing the installer file. How can i pass these parameters to build the container if i save the image instead of use dockerfile ?